# 502 google.bintray.com Bad Gateway

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have started to build Gradle in my android project but I had the following problem, does anyone know what happens?

I'm trying to get the Tflite dependency from Maven, never had a problem until today.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :tflite
      > Failed to list versions for org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Comment: https://status.bintray.com/

Comment: My team has also been having problems pulling dependencies from Bintray, and i'm seeing some blog posts from JFrog that they will be shutting down Bintray. Relevant blog post here https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/
I'll update when I find a solution, i.e., another repository to migrate to.

Comment: @JakeSchnorr Update my question, try this [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502/70388139#70388139)

Comment: I think the appropriate long term solution here is to simply migrate away from any JFrog repos as they have become unreliable, even through their commitment to "remain read-only".

Answer (score 3):

We experienced the same the last two days. It looks like it is working again.

Comment: Not working in the last 4 days.

Comment: @Josteve Update my question, try this [my question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502?noredirect=1#comment124315942_70309075)

Comment: Not Working until now, any update?

Answer (score 1):

after 3 days working on a such problem

I solved it by editing the project buildgradle
[appname]/build.gradle
as below

```
    repositories {
        google()
    //commit this: maven
       //maven() 
    // add this
        mavenCentral() 
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    //commit this: maven
       //maven() 
    // add this
        mavenCentral() 
    }
}
```

Bonus:
i had the same problem with the same library so maybe you need this setting on the same build.gradle file
Kotlin version:

```
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
```

dependencies:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have issues with JCenter / Bintray, you can switch to JitPack.

All you need to do is to search the GitHub project of your choice in https://jitpack.io then copy-paste the provided code in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Update my question, try this [my question ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502/70388139#70388139)

Answer (score 0):

Comment jcenter() and add mavenCentral()

```
 repositories {
       jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
```