# Android studio Bintray 502 bad gateway

Tags: android, android-studio, bintray, brightcove, http-status-code-502

I'm getting 502 from Bintray when I try to run my Android app.
I've tried:
Clear cache/restart
Updating my gradle version
Updating Exoplayer version

Still getting the error from Bintray.
Best regards.

[The screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1566.png)

> 

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDevDebug'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.brightcove.player:exoplayer2:6.8.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.brightcove.player:exoplayer2:6.8.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/brightcove/player/exoplayer2/6.8.1/exoplayer2-6.8.1.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/brightcove/player/exoplayer2/6.8.1/exoplayer2-6.8.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
> Could not resolve com.brightcove.player:android-ssai-plugin:6.8.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.brightcove.player:android-ssai-plugin:6.8.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/brightcove/player/android-ssai-plugin/6.8.1/android-ssai-plugin-6.8.1.pom'.
> Could not HEAD 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/brightcove/player/android-ssai-plugin/6.8.1/android-ssai-plugin-6.8.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
> Could not resolve com.comscore:android-analytics:6.+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Failed to list versions for com.comscore:android-analytics.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/jayrambhia/maven/com/comscore/android-analytics/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jayrambhia/maven/com/comscore/android-analytics/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/jayrambhia/maven/com/comscore/android-analytics/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Comment: Check if the dependency exist somewhere else, time to move away from bintray/jcenter
https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Comment: Update my question, try this [502 bintray and flutter ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502?noredirect=1#comment124315942_70309075)

Answer (score 1):

Basic problem that version of **com.comscore:android-analytics:6.+** is not specified strictly and gradle have to find possible versions but google.bintray.com is down - no version listing available

1. Find what version is - this **6.+** mean take max version in 6.x.x
2. Search for possible versions [Maven search](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.comscore/android-analytics).
3. Constrain your transitive dependency with maximum possible version 6.7.2

Edit your project **app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  constraints {
    implementation('com.comscore:android-analytics') {
        version {
            strictly '6.7.2'
        }
    }
  }
}
```