# TFLITE plugin is not working for emotion detection app in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, tflite

I'm trying to use `tflite` plugin to use model for emotion detection app. But there is an error showed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> No signature of method: build_29ou9k6xal0pml6qvuo3exmb2.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_29ou9k6xal0pml6qvuo3exmb2$_run_closure2) values: [build_29ou9k6xal0pml6qvuo3exmb2$_run_closure2@4db06c22]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I see the same problem. In the tflite gradle file there are dependencies for `compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'` which I believe is the root cause of the problem. I'm not sure how gradle is supposed to import and compile `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+`.

Comment: I was able to successfully build after following steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution the problem was in the Gradle file which has to be changed from compile to API.
The new implementation of Gradle 7.0 and up replaced the **compile** configuration with **API** but the **tflite plugin** is not updated to match Gradle 7 configuration.

**You will find the file in this location in windows**

```
C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle
```

**Or you can use relative path**

```
%AppData%\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle
```

**OR extract the path from the error message.**

[For more information please visit Gradl website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#changes_7.0)

Table 1. Common configuration upgrades

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Masood AL-BADAWI. He means to replace **compile** with **implementation** in the mentioned file

```
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24
```

The lines should be like:

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
    }
```