# Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+

Tags: flutter, dart, tflite

I'm having trouble running my flutter app
I try several solutions but still has an error
seems that the problem is with the tflite

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :flutter_tflite
> > Failed to list versions for org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Read timed out

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: have you tried addin multiDexEnabled true? inside build.gradle.

Comment: @JitenPatel yup. it does not fix the issue

Comment: you are using which plugin? tflite or flutter_tflite?

Comment: @JitenPatel I'am using flutter_tflite

Comment: if I'm not wrong then this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter, right?

Comment: @JitenPatel yep that's what Im using

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the issue.

what I did is change the

> build.gradle

of the tflite plugin from jcenter() because jcenter is already been shutdown [details here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration) into mavenCentral().

you can change it directly in

> C:\Users\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org

locate the folder of tflite plugin you're using

[image]

and I set a default version of tflite so I can work with it offline Or online

[image]

some did also address the issue here in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502)